# log user on to a different URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

So I have an admin panel for a web site on a different url than the main site. We currently hash the passwords for all users on the main site. What the client wants is a way to auto log into the main site from the admin site. I am having issues accomplishing this because cross url session setting is a real pain. So far I've tried a web service and using HttpWebRequest to hit a web page that will auto log in the user. None of these work because of session issues.

So I guess my question would be, what is the best way to accomplish this? It has to be ultra secure too. I am currently using a time expiring hash for secure login.

### Update

I was thinking about Open ID. Although I cannot use it because we have an already defined authentication system, the idea is the same, I want to develop something like that without modifying my authentication logic.

Comment: Need to look for SSO (Single Sign-On). Not going to be fun, but can be done. And you're right, it will need a service to operate in the back-end (with probably an authentication token in the redirecting URL).

Comment: Just looked up SSO. It seems to be more for windows based authentication. This is one of those custom authentications, so I really can't create a bunch of new windows users; unless I misunderstood what SSO means.

Comment: @JohnathanKong: SSO is just the premise of using a single log-in for multiple sites, not the method/implementation. This can be done with both Windows/Forms authentication, or any other form of authentication you can think of. (Or maybe it's my semantics, but to _me_ SSO is a [broad term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on), inclusive of windows auth (among others).)

Comment: You're right. I was just looking it up, and SSO is what OpenID is based on. I understand the concept, but implementation is going to be very rocky.

Comment: @JohnathanKong: What's typically done are service endpoints on either side the site can call in the back-end to pre-verify they have a user coming and set things up. The "handshake" then returns a token that's their key to get on. From there, we provide the key to the new site as a confirmation that we're who the site just pre-authenticated. Then you do the cleanup and build the session and you're in. (in layman's terms, but the premise)

Comment: Yup, that's what I understood from what I've found. There's a lot of talking going back and forth. The issue that I'd have with this type of implementation is that I'd have to create a master login or create master users, then I have to modify authentication logic to enable users to choose who they want to log in as from the front end.

Comment: @JohnathanKong: Safe to assume you have two different logins currently (one for admin, one for the general site? [and each with their own membership database]) With SSO, it may make sense consolidating the information and just adding an admin flag to the user on the "main site" (which would then be verified when they try to access the admin panel).

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Two different types of log ins, but unfortunately unification is not on our list right now, and I'm already starting to go over budget with all these dead ends I'm encountering.

Comment: @JohnathanKong: Least amount of effort is probably going to be turning your main site in to the master list, adding an admin flag (with any other prefs/settings the Admin Control Panel [ACP] needs), and forcing the ACP to authenticate through the main site (which also implements SSO). But ultimately you know the system better and I'm probably not telling you anything you don't already know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am doing is to use a database to share sessions/user IDs:

- In web app A, I have a link to web app B.
- The link has a unique log in ID (e.g. the session ID) of web app A as a parameter.

The "workflow" then goes roughly like this:

1. When the user clicks the link (or just in `Page_Load`), the session ID is stored to DB.
2. Web app B is being opened, the session ID of web app A is being passed.
3. Web app B looks in the database and searches for the session ID of web app A.
4. When it is found, some security checks are done (e.g. age of record).
5. If everything is OK, the user is logged in in web app B.

The table has kind of structure like this:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| ID | SessionID | UserID | DateWhenThisRecordWasCreated |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

With this configuration you can pass log ins between various related applications, they only have to get access the the same database. (If you cannot share the database, one could think of web app A providing a SOAP web service that web app B can query instead).

I cannot imagine any security whole in this; on the other hand, if someone can think of one, I'll be very glad to hear your feedback.

Comment: In the age of Wifi, I have a very cool piece of software that allows me to scan the connections around me for GET/POST requests (inclusive of SIDs) that I can then run in my own browser and be authenticated. ;-)

Comment: So adding e.g. the IP address in addition to the SessionID to the table would help?

Comment: @Brad Wouldn't this app be running over HTTPS?  That would protect from most sniffing-based attacks.

Comment: The only suggestion I would have is to replace the pre-determined SessionID with a one-time "ticket" ID that will be invalidated after a single use.  This will eliminate the possibility of replay attacks due to a compromised client.